# How to check whether the alarm time has been elapsed before setting the alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have tried the below method of checking the alarm time with the current time in millis,its working fine in most of the cases but when i set the alarm for eg. @4:07 p.m(i.e just few mins after exact hour) then the comparison fails..

```
operation_morn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_morn,
                intent, 0);
        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        long current_time = calNow.getTimeInMillis();
        // Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
        // calNow.set(selected_Year, selected_Month, selected_Day);
        calNow.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selected_Day);
        calNow.set(Calendar.MONTH, (selected_Month - 1));
        calNow.set(Calendar.YEAR, selected_Year);
        calNow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
        calNow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
        calNow.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);



        long alarm_time_in_millis = calNow.getTimeInMillis();
        if (alarm_time_in_millis > current_time) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNow.getTimeInMillis(),
                    operation_morn);

        }
```

Comment: If alarm time is already elapsed, then the alarm will fire immediately.

Comment: yes,that's what I have to ignore.

Comment: yes correct, you can log the milliseconds and check for the reason.

Comment: I have debugged the code and found that the alarm time in milliseconds in that case is less than the current time in millis which technically and logically should not be :(

Comment: Be careful while setting Calendar.AM and Calendar.PM, From Where you are getting selected_day and selected_month values? why you subtract 1 from selected_month while you are not subtracting it from selected_day? Would you please explain you code in more detail?

Comment: See I am sending selected day and selected month as parameters for this method and as month value in android calendar starts from 0 and here the selected month parameter value is the normal month count which we use daily that's why I have to subtract 1 from only month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here

```
calNow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours)); // It sets hour for 24 hours format.
```

This should be

```
calNow.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hours));
```

---

*This is wrong because your are setting AM/PM your self by doing `calNow.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM)`. If you are handling 24 hours format then remove this line only. This will solve your problem.*

---

And for time comparison you can use [`Timestamp`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Timestamp.html), which having method to compare two times. Although you can use [`Calender`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) also to compare times.

```
Timestamp alramTimeStamp = new Timestamp(calNow.getTimeInMillis());
Timestamp currentTimeStamp = new Timestamp(current_time);
if (alramTimeStamp.after(currentTimeStamp)) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNow.getTimeInMillis(),
            operation_morn);
}
```

Comment: cool dude,lemme give it a try..See Pankaj here I am making an alarm app where I have to show a reminder before 10mins of the actual alarm time and also fire an alarm at the right time.So I have used the below logic : long alarm_time_morning_before = calNow.getTimeInMillis()- (10 * 60 * 1000); Is this correct logically

Comment: No. There should be two alarms. One for notification other for original alarm. Both can be set at the same time when you set the actual alarm.

Comment: yes I have done the same thing bro and I just wanna confirm whether the logic which I have used to set the alarm 10 mins before is correct or not ??

Comment: Ohh yes. Thats fine. Other way is to minus 10 from minutes from the calender calNow. But donot forget to keep timemilli in other variable before doing.

Comment: Hey I am getting problem when I try to set alarm near to an exact hour for eg. 6:05 p.m i.e two alarms will be set one 10 mins before and other exactly 6:05 p.m.But it does not set any one of them. :(

Comment: SHow me the code. And check if the both times are correct. If one is working another must work.